# How to switch views with animation - objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uianimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a viewController that has a tableView and a mapView, and only one is visible.
I also have a toolbar with segment control with two buttons (list and map)

How do I switch between the table view and the map view ? and it's important that the toolbar will stay locked without animating with the views.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After more thinking I found a solution, add another view as a container view for both table view and map view.
This way i can do:

```
   [UIView transitionWithView:self.someContainerView
                     duration:1.0
                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                     animations:^{
                         self.mapView.hidden   = !showingMapView;
                         self.tableView.hidden = showingMapView;
                     } completion:nil
    ];
```

without flipping the toolbar

Comment: If this is how you solved your problem, mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: How? when I press the "accept answer check mark" it say I can accept my own answer in two days

Comment: Alright, sorry I forgot about that limitation. Just making sure!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `UIView` animation transition, passing the transitioning views' superview:

```
- (IBAction)segmentIndexChanged {
   BOOL showingMapView = (BOOL)self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
   [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                     duration:1.0
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                   animations:^{
     self.mapView.hidden   = !showingMapView;
     self.tableView.hidden = showingMapView;
   } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: thanks the problem is that my toolbar is also animating, I think because he is also a subclass of the view

Comment: @Eyal you most likely mean that it is a subview and not a subclass, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for show table and mapview:

Hide the mapview and tableview in segmentedControlIndexChanged:

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlIndexChanged {
    switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0: //it's show tableview
            [UIView transitionWithView: self.view
                              duration:1.0 
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                            animations:^{
                                self.mapView.hidden   = YES;
                                self.tableView.hidden = NO; }
                            completion:nil];

              break;

        case 1: //it's show mapview
            [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                              duration:1.0
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                            animations:^{
                                self.mapView.hidden   = NO;
                                self.tableView.hidden = YES; }
                            completion:nil];
            break;

        default:
              break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks the problem is that my toolbar is also animating, I think because he is also a subclass of the view